# How to catch click event in resource view of DHTMLX Gantt?

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I am making complex gantt page using `DHTMLX Gantt Pro` version.
There is resource view bottom of task view.
[image]
I want to catch `click` event in there.
I tried with **onTaskClick** event. But it's only working for task area.

```
gantt.attachEvent("onTaskClick", function (id, e) {
  console.log("onTaskClick", id, e);
  return true;
});
```

How to catch `click` event in resource area?
Please anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Please beware that gantt can repaint elements any time. So if you attach event listeners to individual buttons - these handlers will be lost after next repaint, when the resource elements will be cleared and rendered again. So if you use the approach suggested in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940403/how-to-catch-click-event-in-resource-view-of-dhtmlx-gantt#answer-65942808), you'll have to attach event handlers to rows each time their html is refreshed because of data repaint or due to the smart rendering.

A more reliable option would be to add a listener for "click" event to the top element of the gantt, and then inspect event target inside the handler function. If you detect that the event target is your button - you run the action, if the event target is some other element - you ignore that event.

This approach is also called [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). That way you can catch events on any element inside the gantt, without need to attach handler to every element when it's rendered.

Html can be the same as in @KhamNai reply:

```
<div name="remove"><img src="some icon" /></div>
```

But I suggest different code:

```
gantt.event(gantt.$container, "click", function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    // check if the target element is our button:
    if(target.closest("[name='remove']")) { //Element.closest doesn't work in IE, use polifyll if you need it
        // if it's the resource button - do the action
        var row = target.closest("[data-resource-id]");
        var resourceId = row.getAttribute("data-resource-id");
        alert("delete resource " + resourceId);
    }
});
```

Live example: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/58a6b1639

Comment: @Daniel.Wang Can you post code snippet so I could check what's wrong?

When you "click" event on the top element, you'll capture clicks on all nested elements. So the only tricky part is to detect which clicks are fired from your button, this is done by inspecting `event.target`.
Can you pls show the button html and js of your click handler?
you can post it here, or on our forum
https://forum.dhtmlx.com/c/gantt

Comment: Thank you for your help. right now my problem was fixed by first method.

Comment: Btw, Are you developer in dhtmlx? if you're in dhtmlx, I hope you make click event for resources part in next version.

Comment: Yes, I work for dhtmlx. We've added api handlers for resource panel events to our TODO for the next update:)

Comment: thanks. when it available? i'm a premium user in dhtmlx. i loved dhtmlx product and buyed dhtmlx gantt, suit, spreadsheet, and richedittext enterprise license.

Comment: and there is scroll problem in resource view dhtmlx gantt.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch event with `gantt.event()` function.
Here is suitable link for you.
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_event.html

first, you need to set the name each element.

in template code you needs return html string as following.

```
<div name="remove"><img src="some icon" /></div>
```

and then you like catch event when gantt rendered.

```
var elements = [].slice.call(gantt.$container.querySelectorAll("[name='remove']");
elements.forEach(element => {
    gantt.event(element, "click", function(event) {
        // here is your process
    });
});
```